SSL routines::legacy sigalg disallowed or unsupported] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
I´m trying to run a FastAPI connected to SQL Server on a Docker container, but I´m getting this error when I execute the query.
Error executing: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A00014D:SSL routines::legacy sigalg disallowed or unsupported] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)') 

This is the code:
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import datetime as dt

def mssql_engine(user='sa', password='password', host='xxx.xxx.x.xxx', db='dbname', driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'):
    engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{password}@{host}/{db}?driver={driver}&Trusted_Connection=yes&Encrypt=no")
    return engine


def execute_query():
    fecha = dt.datetime.now().date().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    query = f"select @@version"

    try:
        df = pd.read_sql(query, mssql_engine())
        return len(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error executing: '+str(e))
        return e

print(execute_query())

pass

And this is the Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12.4-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg2 apt-transport-https unixodbc-dev && \
    curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17


COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000


CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

What should I do? I tried everything. If I run it on Python Debugger, it works perfectly, but not on Docker. I am using SQL Server 2008, build Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22.

What does PRINT @@VERSION; return on the SQL Server instance?

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22...
I know, it´s an old version, but it should work if it works without docker, really? It´s a huge db, so I cannot migrate to a newer version...

Wow.. it's bad enough that you are running a version that is end of life, you should have upgraded 5+ years ago,but the real problem is there has NEVER been a single update installed on the instance in 16 years: that's outright negligence... That's the problem... Update and upgrade. Get rid of was ever in charge of updating that server; they never did the job.

"it should work if it works without docker, really?" It shouldn't work now, no. The fact that it is means the host you're connecting from where it works also, likely, is lacking updates. Both hosts are using TLS1.1 or earlier, which is a severe security concern.

don't you mean that your python is running on docker, not sql server?

If I run the Python code on VSC, it works, and returns me the query result, but with docker, I get that error. @siggemannen

@ThomA Yes, I know, I´m on a new job and they have the database with that version, but it´s really really huge, and I cannot take the risk of migrating it.

Because your python in VSCode is also running on an insecure host that likely hasn't been updated in years too, @JulianToujas (though hopefully it's had some recently and it's not a Windows 7 machine...). The solution is get the last 16 years of updates installed (across the domain it seems) and then upgrade ASAP.

@ThomA my python is running on my pc with Windows 11, SQL Server 2020, and Python 3.12.4, everything is updated.

I'm guessing python is using the libs on the machine it's running on, and in docker the older ssl is disabled which makes it fail. You can try encrypt=false setting when connecting, but as @ThomA is hinting, it seems like it's time to upgrade

Windows 11 has TLS 1.1 and older disabled out of the box, @JulianToujas , which means someone has actively re-enabled it. That's like putting a piece of paper over a hole in the wall and declaring the problem "fixed", where actually it's a (very) temporary solution at best.

"SQL Server 2020"? That doesn't exist

haha, well, I understand. I will try to figure out with my partners if we can do something, but seems like it´s time to update, thanks.

@ThomA omg, I mean 2019, sorry

It was time to update In 2008; there were several patches for SQL Server 2008 released the same year it was released. The reason the problem you are having is because you're missing these updates, which includes TLS1.2 support. The time to upgrade (to a supported version of SQL Server) was also 5 years ago.

Yes I know, of course I would did it. But I arrived 2 months ago, I wasn´t here on 2008

Yes, but someone was, and that's why I'm being so vocal; someone didnt do their job for 16 years. 16 years... It's clear your employer has been kept in the dark, or they were being intentionally neglectful as a company. I like to hope it's the former and someone needs to show them how bad the problem is.

Aside... apt-key add has been deprecated since Debian 9 days. You really should be using gpg --dearmor or something more modern in your Dockerfiles.

Aside... if you docker run -it --rm python:3.12.4-slim cat /etc/os-release you'll see that your base image is using Debian 12. Your apt repo references should be targeting Debian 12 (Bookworm), not Debian 10 (Buster), or you'll potentially be pulling in wrong versions of packages (i.e.: ones that are incompatible with your current operating system or even with each other).

One advantage of never upgrading your servers is that I bet your company was unaffected by the recent CrowdStrike outage. On the other hand, hackers from all corners of the globe might be periodically and quietly harvesting and selling your data. Best to make a case to your manager for shelving your current project and create a new project for (1) upgrading your servers with supported software versions with the latest security patches for each, and (2) establishing a maintenance plan for keeping them up-to-date. That will also likely solve your SSL issues without further compromising security.

"One advantage of never upgrading your servers is that I bet your company was unaffected by the recent CrowdStrike outage" you'd have though, @TN , but a vendor we use was affected and I found out (due to them sending us a backup of our data while they were out) that they are using SQL Server build 10.50.4339.0. Go on, Google when they came out...
